# Pressing button holding till the action perform in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, multithreading, web-services, button

I have called a web service method to insert some data and uploading some images to web url.
It is working fine but the button remain pressed till the method perform.I have used threading concept here and created one another thread and perform that action but that thread is not taking me back to the main thread.

Please till me what would be the appropriate way of doing this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web service calling mechanism place in one seperate method and call that method from the IBAction of the button using the performSelector:withObject:andDelay () method.  This will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create one another function in which you can put the code for the webservice call so that your button press issue will be solved.

Comment: If webservice code is not in the buttonClick event then your button should not look press!!!

Comment: I don't think Yashesh this could be helpful.I have tried the solution provided by Bhanu and it solved the problem .

Comment: yes,but creating another function and calling that function from your button click method is the same thing.If you will try then you will get to know.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can implement this using [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html).

```
- (IBAction)buttonPress:(id)sender
{
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{
           //place your web service code here
   });
}
```